# Empty Json in Spring MVC Response Entity

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc

I'm playing around with replacing Java with Scala in my Spring MVC application and so far everything works fine except for serialization of case case class in return body.

Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Array("/level"))
class GameMapController {

@Autowired
private val gameMapService: GameMapService = null

@RequestMapping(value = Array("/{levelNumber}"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
def getGameMap(@PathVariable levelNumber: Int): ResponseEntity[GameMap] = {
  new ResponseEntity[GameMap](gameMapService.getGameMap(levelNumber), HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

and case class to be returned in body looks like this:

```
@Document
case class GameMap(@Id id: String, levelNumber: Int, width: Int, height: Int)
```

I checked if GameMap object have any properties set but i still receive empty Json in response.
What did I miss? Do I need to provide some custom deseralization for Scala class?

Comment: Not too sure how to work Spring MVC with Scala, but are you actually returning anything in your method

Comment: Can you debug if you are getting proper `levelNumber` and for that you are getting proper `GameMap` from function `gameMapService.getGameMap()` ?

Comment: I did. It's not a problem of not retrieving any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a old thread. But answering this as I faced same issue myself.

I solved this by adding Scala Annotation [@BeanProperty](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/beans/BeanProperty.html)

```
@Document
case class GameMap(@Id @BeanProperty id: String, @BeanProperty levelNumber: Int, @BeanProperty width: Int, @BeanProperty height: Int)
```

This creates a getter & setters following the Java Bean convention which is recognize by mapper.